# WooCommerce get_author_posts_url() - Author URL redirecting to shop base

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, user-roles, author-template

I've noticed that when I have WooCommerce enabled and use `get_author_posts_url()` it automatically redirects to the 'shop base' when the user's role is `Customer`.

When I change the user to `Subscriber` `get_author_posts_url()` works correctly.

I've disabled all plugins to systematically identify what was causing the issue and can confirm that it's only when WooCommerce is enabled. I've also flushed rewrites. I've also even tried using `$user->add_role( 'subscriber' )` to the user's capabability array.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can suppress it? (i.e. don't redirect  `get_author_posts_url()` for users with a `customer` role.

**EDIT**

I believe this to be a bug, I've opened a bug ticket with WC and have posted on the [WP forum thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-get_author_posts_url-redirecting-to-shop-base/)

For now I've just set all 'customer' users to 'subscribers' when I get a reply/make any headway I will post back here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Does `get_author_posts_url()` return the URL for customers too? Or it redirects because no URL is outputted?

Comment: Hi Jack, `get_author_posts_url()` does return the url for customers. I've run `wp_list_authors('hide_empty=0')` and all of the URLs are the same. The thing is that if the user is a customer, then it redirects. So, the redirection doesn't appear to be happening because there is no URL being outputted.

Answer (score 1):

I found!

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-author-page-to-custom-user-role/#post-8807168

So in WooCommerce, this is achieved by the following code in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-user-functions.php:

```
/**
 * Disable author archives for customers.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
function wc_disable_author_archives_for_customers() {
    global $wp_query, $author;

    if ( is_author() ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $author );

        if ( isset( $user->roles[0] ) && 'customer' === $user->roles[0] ) {
            wp_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_disable_author_archives_for_customers' );


In your theme’s functions.php (or somewhere else appropriate), you could turn that off:

/* This removes the function that redirects customers to the shop page */
function enable_author_archives_for_customers() {
  remove_action('template_redirect', 'wc_disable_author_archives_for_customers');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'enable_author_archives_for_customers' );
```